# SFML How to orbit around around the center of the screen while moving down?

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

So i have to move a sprite that orbits around the center of the screen (which is the original position of the object in X) while moving down. I have yet to find the way to get it to work, since the sprite flickers everywhere around the screen.

```
move(0, speed);
angle = getRotation();
rotate(+1);
move(origPosX + cosf(angle) * speed, origPosY + sinf(angle) * speed);
```

Comment: And your question is? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how to move a sprite that should orbit around the center of the screen in SFML c++?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], there is too much information missing to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only assume you're running the code in your question every frame, in which case, you should be using `setPosition`, not `move`, otherwise it will be adding the position offset for the rotation constantly.

You also add 1 to the rotation every frame, which unless you lock your framerate, is going to be inconsistent, so I recommend multiplying by the time since last frame (AKA "delta time").

Also, rotation in SFML is done in degrees, but `cosf` takes arguments in radians, so you need to convert that.

You want to do something like this:

```
position += sf::Vector2f(0.f, speed);
rotate(1.f * deltaTime);
setPosition(position.y + cosf(toRadians(angle)), position.y + sinf(toRadians(angle)));
```